# Dynamic table names with Linq to entities? 

Tags: dynamic, linq-to-entities, entity

I wondered if there is a way to provide a table name for linq query at runtime. I am interested in simple query like

```sql
select * from @someTableName
```

I've searched a lot for the answer but couldn't find any help on the net. There was a post on MSDN --> 
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2ed89351-de14-4eff-9b14-e51649c51136)

Dave Russel suggested to do:

```sql
var p = ctx.GetType.GetProperty(oName).getValue(ctx,null)
```

But apart from getting property with reflection I don't know how to work out the rest in order to be able to execute queries against that property like:

```sql
from x in p select x;
```

Comment: IMO when you do this you will be missing the power of LINQ. Why not use plain old SQL?

Comment: I need to have an IQueryable as a result as its gonna be required later.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) method. You execute a SQL query and obtain ObjectResult. Please note that this method is available only in Entity Framework v4.

Comment: It's not at all clear from the question if he *really* wants table names or if he actually wants entity names. This method will use table names. For entity names, use ESQL or `System.Linq.Dynamic`.

Comment: I have various tables with various columns and they are all mapped to Entity Model. So at runtime I pick some table name and retrieve all records from that particular table. So all I have at runtime is table name but I dunno how to use it in order to retrive data(need ordered IQueryable for jqGrid). Doesnt ExecuteStoreQuery has to be parametrized before compilation or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Oh and entity names are same as table names in data store.

Comment: Craig is right about Entity SQL. In case you have entity name corresponding to the table name and their structure coincides as well, then the best solution seems to be the CreateQuery method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670.aspx - here is an example, you can just cast ObjectQuery<T> to IQueryable<T>.